# Helping to solve the algorithm by dynamic programming

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming

**I try to solve a Longest Anchored Comb Problem by dynamic programming but do not know how to achieve the algorithm. Codes except the algorithm have been written down below.**

**Can someone tell me how to solve the algorithm part?**

***Here are the definition of the problem.***

In the list of numbers, any subsequence in this array of the form A[i1], A[i1 + 1], A[i2], A[i2 + 1], . . . , A[ik], A[ik + 1] of 2k elements of array A, for some integer k ≥ 1, and for some indices 1 ≤ i1 < i1 + 1 < i2 < i2 + 1 < · · · < ik < ik + 1 ≤ n such that A[i1] < A[i1 + 1] > A[i2] < A[i2 + 1] > A[i3] < · · · > A[ik] < A[ik + 1], is called a comb.

We call a given comb A[i1], A[i1 + 1], A[i2], A[i2 + 1], . . . , A[ik], A[ik + 1] anchored if A[i1] = A[ik] .

***3 examples:***

1. For instance if A[1, 3, 10, 15, 21], n = 5, then because this sequence is increasing, the longest comb has length k = 1, and such longest comb is
   not unique, e.g., 1, 3; 3, 10; 15, 21 – are examples of 3 longest and anchored combs, each of length 1, i.e., each having one tooth. The output in this instance is therefore 1. Another example of the input array A = [5, 3, 2, 1] with n = 4, where the sequence is decreasing means that there is no comb there, so the output to the Longest Anchored Comb Problem is 0.
2. Another input A[1, 3, 2, 11, 12, 10, 11, 2, 23] with n = 9. Here subsequence A[1], A[2], A[3], A[4], A[6], A[7], A[8], A[9], which is
   1, 3, 2, 11, 10, 11, 2, 23,is a comb of length k = 4 (with 4 teeth), but it is not anchored because the first elements of its first and last teeth are not equal: A[1] = 1 and A[8] = 2. However, subsequence A[3], A[4], A[6], A[7], A[8], A[9] which is 2, 11, 10, 11, 2, 23 is an anchored comb of length k = 3 (with 3 teeth), because the first elements of its first and last teeth are equal: A[3] = 2 and A[8] = 2. This is also the longest anchored comb in this instance, so the output to the Longest Anchored Comb problem is 3.

3.Suppose, for instance, that n = 10 and that the input sequence is:
1 3 2 4 3 5 4 6 1 3,
that is, A[1] = 1, A[2] = 3, A[3] = 2, A[4] = 4, A[5] = 3, A[6] = 5, A[7] =
4, A[8] = 6, A[9] = 1, A[10] = 3. Then, for instance, A[2] = 3, A[4] =
4, A[5] = 3, A[6] = 5 is an anchored comb of length 2, but the longest anchored comb is the whole array and has length 5.

```
 import javax.xml.crypto.Data;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.lang.reflect.Array;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

    public static ArrayList<String> ReadData(String pathname) {
      ArrayList<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>();
      try {

        File filename = new File(pathname);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream(filename));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        int j = 0;
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            strlist.add(line);
        }
        return strlist;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strlist;
}

public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > DataWash(ArrayList<String> Datalist) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > AIS = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> >();
    ArrayList<Integer> IS = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Datalist.size(); i++) {
        String Tstr = Datalist.get(i);
        if (Tstr.equals("A") == false) {
            IS.add(Integer.parseInt(Tstr));
        }
        if (Tstr.equals("A")) {
            ArrayList<Integer> elemAIS = new ArrayList<Integer>(IS);
            AIS.add(elemAIS);
            IS.clear();
        }
    }
    return AIS;
}


  //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Procedure LongestComb() that contains code to write. 
    //These codes are to complete:
    
public static int LongestComb(int[] A, int n){
    /* Input is array of input sequence (a_1 <= a_2 <= ... <= a_n) as A[0,1,...,n-1], that is,
    a_1 = A[0], a_2 = A[1], ..., a_n = A[n-1].
    n = number of integers in sequence A
    This procedure returns the value of the longest anchored comb (>= 1) or 0 if there is no anchored comb. It should not return the respective anchored comb.
    */


    /* 
                   Given an array T[1,...,n] 
                   then M = max_{k: some condition C(k) holds} [ T[k] ],
                   M denotes the largest value T[k] over all indices k such that condition C(k) holds.
    .....
    .....
    */

    /* Here should be the statement and description of the running time
    analysis: describe how the running time depends on
    n (length of the input sequence), and give short argument.

    .....
    ..... 
    */

    /* Here should be the code to solve the problem:
  

    .....
    .....
    return ...;
    */

} // end of procedure LongestComb()


public static int Computation(ArrayList<Integer> Instance, int opt){
    // opt=1 here means option 1 as in -opt1, and opt=2 means option 2 as in -opt2
    int NGounp = 0;
    int size = 0;
    int Correct = 0;
    size = Instance.size();

    int [] A = new int[size-opt];
    // NGounp = Integer.parseInt((String)Instance.get(0));
    NGounp = Instance.get(0); // NOTE: NGounp = 0 always, as it is NOT used for any purpose
                                       // It is just the first "0" in the first line before instance starts.
    for (int i = opt; i< size;i++ ){
        A[i-opt] = Instance.get(i);
    }
    int Size =A.length;
    if (NGounp >Size ){
        return (-1);
    }
    else {
        //Size
        int R = LongestComb(A,Size);
        return(R);
    }
}

public static String Test;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        String msg = "Rerun with flag: " +
        "\n\t -opt1 to get input from dataOne.txt " + 
        "\n\t -opt2 to check results in dataTwo.txt";
        System.out.println(msg);
        return;
    }
    Test = args[0];
    int opt = 2;
    String pathname = "dataTwo.txt";
    if (Test.equals("-opt1")) {
        opt = 1;
        pathname = "dataOne.txt";
    }


    ArrayList<String> Datalist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Datalist = ReadData(pathname);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer> > AIS = DataWash(Datalist);

    int Nins = AIS.size();
    int NGounp = 0;
    int size = 0;
    if (Test.equals("-opt1")) {
        for (int t = 0; t < Nins; t++) {
            int Correct = 0;
            int Result = 0;
            ArrayList<Integer> Instance = AIS.get(t);
            Result = Computation(Instance, opt);
            System.out.println(Result);
        }
    }
    else {
        int wrong_no = 0;
        int Correct = 0;
        int Result = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> Wrong = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int t = 0; t < Nins; t++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> Instance = AIS.get(t);
            Result = Computation(Instance, opt);
            System.out.println(Result);
            Correct = Instance.get(1);
            if (Correct != Result) {
                Wrong.add(t+1);
                wrong_no=wrong_no+1;
            }
        }
        if (Wrong.size() > 0) {System.out.println("Index of wrong instance(s):");}
        for (int j = 0; j < Wrong.size(); j++) {
            System.out.print(Wrong.get(j));
            System.out.print(",");

            /*ArrayList Instance = (ArrayList)Wrong.get(j);
            for (int k = 0; k < Instance.size(); k++){
                System.out.println(Instance.get(k));
            }*/
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Percentage of correct answers:");
        System.out.println(((double)(Nins-wrong_no) / (double)Nins)*100);

    }

 }
```

}